# innerHtml command not working Advise please

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in Javascript and this is my first post in Stackoverflow. I follow a book to play with some javascript functions. Here I am stocked by the innerHtml method. It supposedly should work but it's not. I looked different places and can't figure out the reason. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href = "popupA.html" id = "link">Link</a>
  <p id = "p1">paragraph 1</p>
  <p id = "p2">paragraph 2</p>
<script>
document.getElementById('link').href = 'popupB.html'; //works

document.getElementById('p1').innerText = 'sample1'; //works

var a = document.getElementById('p2');

a.innerHtml = "sample 2"; //innerHtml doesn't work here

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. You just have a typo. The property is calles `innerHTML` with uppercase HTML.

```
a.innerHTML = "sample 2"; // uppercase HTML
```

I recommend to use a debugger (e.g. FireBug if you are using Firefox) the next time you have problems with your JavaScript. Debugging code is *way* easier, than staring at it ;)

Comment: YES! That works! thank you very much philipp. But it's weird that the book I am studying "Modern Javascript by larry Ullman" is using " innerHtml " word through out the text and it seems work well.For example: var original = document.getElementById(‘someDiv’).innerHtml; is that possible the author made a mistake? Thanks again for help!

Comment: I cannot find any reference to `innerHtml`. So probably the author was wrong here. It is called `innerHTML` in the spec since at least 2008: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0